# Docker Compose apparently ignores COMPOSE_FILE

Tags: docker-compose

I have two docker-compose config yamls that look like this:

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2'
services:
  web: &web
  build: .
  environment:
    FOO: bar
```

docker-compose.development.override.yml :

```
version: '2'
services:
  web: &web
  build: .
  environment:
    FOO: biz
```

When I take a look at the value of `$FOO` inside the container, I am not seeing the value I expect:

```
bdares$ COMPOSE_FILE=./docker-compose.yml:./docker-compose.development.override.yml
bdares$ docker-compose run --rm web bash
docker$ echo $FOO
bar
```

When I explicitly set the compose files, I see the value I expect:

```
bdares$ docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml \
> -f ./docker-compose.development.override.yml \
> run --rm web bash
docker$ echo $FOO
biz
```

This suggests to me that `docker-compose` is not respecting the `COMPOSE_FILE` environment variable as claimed [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#/compose-file).

What might I be doing wrong?

Version info:

- docker-compose version 1.8.0
- Docker version 1.11.0

Comment: Are you using the bash shell? Depending on the shell you are using you might try to wrap the enviroment variable in double quotes FOO="bar:baz". If you echo the env variable from outside docker is it returned corectly?

Comment: You might need to `export COMPOSE_FILE` for this to work, or move the command onto the same line where you set the value.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
export COMPOSE_FILE=./docker-compose.yml:./docker-compose.development.override.yml
docker-compose run --rm web bash
```

or

```
COMPOSE_FILE=./docker-compose.yml:./docker-compose.development.override.yml docker-compose run --rm web bash
```